# OpenShift : ImportError: No module named gyp: on NodeJs/Mongo cartridge

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, node-gyp, openshift-cartridge

I have a **OpenShift** gear with the **NodeJS** and **MongoDB** cartridge installed. I have added **KeystoneJS** to and when I try to push the updated code, the build fails due to missing `gyp` module. Full error stack below.

Has anyone else faced missing gyp module of a node/mongo cartridge?

Thanks!
Nirav

```
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote: File "/opt/rh/v8314/root/usr/bin/gyp", line 15, in 
remote: import gyp
remote: ImportError: No module named gyp
remote: gyp ERR! configure error
remote: gyp ERR! stack Error: gyp failed with exit code: 1
remote: gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
remote: gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
remote: gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
remote: gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
remote: gyp ERR! command "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
remote: gyp ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/559fa9944382ec4cf1000106/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/keystone-utils/node_modules/limax/node_modules/cld
remote: gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
remote: gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
remote: gyp ERR! not ok
remote:
remote: npm info cld@2.4.3 Failed to exec install script
remote: npm ERR! EEXIST, open '/var/lib/openshift/559fa9944382ec4cf1000106/.npm/0fe9cfe4-6-npm-mime-db-1-14-0-package-tgz.lock'
remote: File exists: /var/lib/openshift/559fa9944382ec4cf1000106/.npm/0fe9cfe4-6-npm-mime-db-1-14-0-package-tgz.lock
remote: Move it away, and try again.
remote: npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
remote: npm ERR! command "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-d"
remote: npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/559fa9944382ec4cf1000106/app-root/runtime/repo
remote: npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
remote: npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
remote: npm ERR! path /var/lib/openshift/559fa9944382ec4cf1000106/.npm/0fe9cfe4-6-npm-mime-db-1-14-0-package-tgz.lock
remote: npm ERR! code EEXIST
remote: npm ERR! errno 47
```

Answer (score 1):

This error started to happen for me suddenly, too, even though it had worked before. For some reason the Python `gyp` module is either not available in the cartridge or cannot be found. Though I cannot tell what has changed I have found a workaround by upgrading the `npm` installation used for deployment.

For this I added two action hooks:

1. `.openshift/action_hooks/pre_build`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   #  We need to move the package.json file out of the way in pre_build, so
   #  that the OpenShift git post-receive hook doesn't try and use the old
   #  npm version to install the dependencies.
   mv ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/package.json \
      ${OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_UUID}_package.json
   ```
2. `.openshift/action_hooks/build`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   #  we moved the package.json file out of the way in pre_build,
   #  so that the OpenShift git post-receive hook doesn't try and use the
   #  old npm version to install the dependencies. Move it back in.
   mv ${OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_UUID}_package.json \
      ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/package.json

   cd ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}

   # We need an updated npm available for node-gyp to work reliable
   npm install npm

   # Now install the packages with the new npm version
   ./node_modules/.bin/npm install
   ```

The idea of using an alternative npm installation that way is taken from https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift/tree/master/.openshift/action_hooks

I also tried using environment variables and setting `$PYTHONPATH` but had no success with that approach during build (although I got it to work on a manual install).